# Is an email processing business halal or haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I want to know if an email processing system is halal or haraam. You are setting up a business website invited by others by paying $25 to him and setup your own business website inviting other users to pay you $25. You carry forward to do the same to earn from the business. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: So, it's a [pyramid scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_scheme)?

Answer (score 0):

و علیکم السلام

As an IT professional I would suggest that you should keep you terms & conditions in a way that your platform/business should not be used for sending emails that are not allowed or disliked in Islam like interest (either for banks or any other organization), pornographic material, fake products, etc ...

الله أعلم

Comment: As most answers on IslamStackExchange include sources to avoid opinions, this shouldn't be an exception. So I ask you, can you put a source that asserts your answer?